# "pydantic\validators.py" : no validator found for <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Tags: pandas, validation, customvalidator, pydantic, python-dataclasses

Below DataFrame of pandas is not validated by pydantic. How to handle this?

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class DataFrames:
    dataframe1: pd.DataFrame = None
    dataframe2: pd.DataFrame = None
```

This throws the following error:

```
File "pydantic\validators.py", line 715, in find_validators

RuntimeError: no validator found for <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config
```

Answer (score 59):

Personally, I'd mistyped the type annotation

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar = Optional[NonNegativeInt]
```

Rather than;

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar: Optional[NonNegativeInt]
```

Silly one ik, but double check that :)

Comment: Slik error....same world

Comment: this is not answering the question

Comment: agree @zaffer. not directly. but clearly folks found it useful.

Comment: @Zaffer I got this error, and on seeing this solution I thought "that's surely not what I've done", and it was. Thanks @Karuhanga!

Comment: Exactly the same error, thanks

Comment: Exact same error, I'm a trash dev

Answer (score 22):

According to the [Pydantic Docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types), you can solve your problems in several ways.

The simplest one is simply to allow arbitrary types in the model config, but this is functionality packaged with the `BaseModel` : quoting [the docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/) again :

> Keep in mind that pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass is a drop-in replacement for dataclasses.dataclass with validation, not a replacement for pydantic.BaseModel

With that in mind, the following code runs fine :

```py
import pandas as pd
from pydantic import BaseModel

class DataFrames(BaseModel):
    dataframe1: pd.DataFrame = None
    dataframe2: pd.DataFrame = None

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

Comment: type error with the `= None`

Comment: Not sure what you mean, everything runs fine with python 3.10 on my machine?

Comment: A DataFrame can't be None, so `dataframe1: pd.DataFrame | None = None` (or `dataframe1: Optional[pd.DataFrame] = None`)

Comment: It is important to note that `arbitrary_types_allowed = True` switches of pydantics type checking. The code will work, but type safety will be compromised.

Answer (score 18):

If you came here with general problem `no validator found for <class 'XYZ'>` you should check missed BaseModel inheritance:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyCustomType: # We forgot inheritance here, should be MyCustomType(BaseModel)
    id: int
    text: str

class MyCustomClass2(BaseModel):
    data: List[MyCustomType]
```

Answer (score 2):

Only adding config in dataclass construction should work :

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(config={"arbitrary_types_allowed": True})
class DataFrames:
    dataframe1: pd.DataFrame = None
    dataframe2: pd.DataFrame = None
```

Comment: Would you note that this applies to pydantic v2, which is incompatible with the widely-used v1?